# Issue in storing special character in a table

Tags: html

In my html Page..there is a dropdown menu..In which there are options like

```
**DEPARTMENT**
1.P&C
2.SARD
3.ORC
```

On clicking any of these options..That particular value should be stored in a table.
But If I choose P&C option ..I am not able to store the value "P&C" instead "PC" is stored as data in my table by truncating the special characters..How to allow special characters to be stored in a table?

Comment: What table do you refer to? How do you produce the html?

Answer (score 1):

There are 5 predefined entity references in XML:

```
&lt;    <   
&gt;    >   
&amp;   &   
&apos;  '   
&quot;  "
```

Soo you need to change `P&C` as `P&amp;C`

Comment: @user3115348 wlc dear.Go ahead and let us knw if face any pblm.

Answer (score 0):

For & use  `P &amp; C`

Similary for < > and other chars

Comment: Truncated here tooo use P "&amp;amp;"